Why is the space of the text inside "{\color{darkgray} }" big?
I have a document
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{0.45, 0.45, 0.45}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{4.5in}p{3.75in}}
A & B  \\

Professeur de mathématiques & Professeur de mathématiques \\
Université Toulouse Capitole &  Université Toulouse Capitole \\
{\color{darkgray} abc} & {\color{darkgray} abc} \\
{\color{darkgray} + 33 (0)5} & {\color{darkgray} + 33 (0)5}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

Could you explain why there is a big space between lines generated by \color{darkgray}?


I cannot explain why, but you can solve the problem using \textcolor{darkgray}{your text} instead.

Thank you very much for above comments.

texdoc grfguide footnote on page 7

@campa not a paragraph actually but does move the reference point of the box.
